# `>` not supported between `str` and `int` when using `input()` in Python

Tags: python

I am in the process of writing a personal code and I seem to have hit a snag. The code should run, but it doesn't. I've copied and pasted it below for you guys to see, and the error. I know it is a simple error, but I can't figure out what it means.

```
print(contents1)

print(contents2)
choose = input("So, what is your answer?")
if choose == 1:
    print(contents3)
else:
    if choose == 2:
        print(contents4)
        number = random.randint(1, 6)
        if number >= 3:
            print(contents5)
        else:
            print(contents6)
            number2 = random.randint(1, 6)
            if number2 >= 2:
                print(contents7)
            else:
                print(contents8)
                useItem1 = input("So, do you use the Holy Hand Grenade, or save "
                                 "it for later?")
                if useItem1 == 1:
                    print(contents9)
                    holy_hand_grenade = holy_hand_grenade - 1
                elif useItem1 == 2:
                    print(contents10)
                else:
                    print(contents11)
                    useItem1 = input("Once again, do you use the Holy Hand Grenade, or save "
                                 "it for later?")
                    if useItem1 == 1:
                        print(contents9)
                        holy_hand_grenade = holy_hand_grenade - 1
                    elif useItem1 == 2:
                        print(contents10)
                    else:
                         print(contents12)
                         sys.quit()
    else:
        if choose == 3:
            print(contents13)
        else:
            if choose > 3:
                print(contents11)
                if choices == 1:
                    print(contents3)
                else:
                    if choose == 2:
                        print(contents4)
                        number = random.randint(1, 6)
                        if number >= 3:
                            print(contents5)
                        else:
                            print(contents6)
                            number2 = random.randint(1, 6)
                            if number2 >= 2:
                                print(contents7)
                            else:
                                print(contents8)
                                useItem1 = input("So, do you use the Holy Hand Grenade, or save "
                                 "it for later?")
                                if useItem1 == 1:
                                    print(contents9)
                                    holy_hand_grenade = holy_hand_grenade - 1
                                elif useItem1 == 2:
                                    print(contents10)
                                else:
                                    print(contents11)
                                    useItem1 = input("Once again, do you use the Holy Hand Grenade, or save "
                                     "it for later?")
                                    if useItem1 == 1:
                                        print(contents9)
                                        holy_hand_grenade = holy_hand_grenade - 1
                                    elif useItem1 == 2:
                                        print(contents10)
                                    else:
                                        print(contents12)
                                        sys.quit()
            else:
                print(contents12)
                sys.quit()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Documents\School\Semester #13\CIS-105\Final Project\boss_fight.py", line 138, in <module>
    first_boss()
  File "C:\Users\Spencer\Documents\School\Semester #13\CIS-105\Final Project\boss_fight.py", line 97, in first_boss
    if choose > 3:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I would greatly appreciate some help. Also, some advice to streamline it would be very welcome.

Comment: It seems that you're comparing a string and an int. Try converting the string to a numeric value first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using Python 3: `input()` returns a string, and `raw_input()` is deprecated. In contrast, in Python 2, `input()` returned a numerical value. For details, refer to [Built-In Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) section of the documentation.

You will need to do something like

```
...
print(contents2)
choose = int(input("So, what is your answer?")) # Notice the `int()` here
...
```

or if you are getting many numbers, use

```
choose_map = map(int, input("So, what are your answers?").split())
choose_list = list(choose_map)
```

If you are using Python 2, and still having this issue, please, provide your list of `import`s. Something might be off there.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition, I would recommend you to use

```
elif choose == 2:
```

Instead of

```
else: 
    if choose == 2:
```